# Should I withdraw from a funded research based graduate program at McMaster?

Tags: graduate-school, supervision, canada, withdraw

I accepted a research-based graduate offer from McMaster University. I applied to other schools but I did not hear back. I assumed I did not get in. So I accepted the offer I had. I know learned that I got into my dream program. However, I feel terrible to withdraw from the offer from McMaster because I genuinely like my supervisor and his students with whom I spoke. It has only been one month since I accepted the offer. I did not accept any money yet or volunteered in the lab. What should I do? And if I were to withdraw my offer, how do I go about it.

Comment: Talk to someone at McMaster.

Comment: For the second question, please search our archives, we have advised many people in the same situation. For example, [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/128017/can-i-decline-a-phd-program-i-have-already-accepted). As for whether you "should" do this, only you can decide. "Words of wisdom" from us won't really help much, you'll have to dive into the weeds of the two opportunities and see what makes the most sense for you.